# How to detect that QRCode is scanned?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, qr-code

I have a Spring web application and I send an email to users and that email  includes a QR code. How can I detect that the QR code is scanned with any phone? I want to detect that process in my web application. I have to do something when the QR code is scanned. However I cannot find how I can make it. Should I use websocket?

Here are my codes:

```java
private JavaMailSender emailSender;
// ....

MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
byte[] qrImageBytes = QRGenBarcodeGenerator.getQRCodeImage("text", 250, 250);
ByteArrayDataSource qrImageDataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(qrImageBytes, "image/png");
helper.addAttachment("qrcode",qrImageDataSource);
emailSender.send(message);
```

`getQrCodeImage` function

```java
public static byte[] getQRCodeImage(String text, int width, int height) throws WriterException, IOException {
    BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
    ByteArrayOutputStream pngOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", pngOutputStream);
    byte[] pngData = pngOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return pngData;
}
```

Comment: Make the content of the QR code a link to your program. If the user accesses the link, the QR code is scanned.

Comment: Hmm. How can I check the user's access to the link with java code ?  Actually I seek answer of that question. I don't know how I can write this control in Java

Comment: You decide where the link goes to. If it goes to a page that id part of your spring boot application, your code can be cslled whenever the user accesses the link.

Comment: Okey mate. I will try.Thanks your suggestions.